# Адапивное изображение

Tags: html, css

У меня есть шаблон, в котором есть картинка:

[image: то, что необходимо по шаблону]

Не понимаю как реализовать всёправильно, т.к вот что получается когда я просто вставляю картинку и меняю свойство border-radius

[image: img with border radius]

а вот что случается когда создаю div с background-image

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вырежьте картинку нужного размера и с нужным закруглением в ближайшем фотошопе без всяких border-radius, что мешает?

Comment: то, что при расширении этой самой картинки она будет "пузатой" :)

Comment: background-image можно позиционировать (центровать по осям, сдвигать к краю, в принципе сдвигать). Поэкспериментируйте